# Selenium python find and replace text

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to replace text within a string on Wagtail backend using Selenium and Python.
My strategy is:

- Find the element that contains the text with contains(text()
- Replace the string I need to replace (in this case some price)
- substitute the old text with the new one

```js
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(), '17,30')]")
newprice= str(element.text).replace('17,30',"1000")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText =  ",newprice, element)
```

This is the error message I get

> selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Unexpected identifier

The following code works but doesn't do what I need. The element that contains "17,30" also contains other text. With the following code, the whole text will be substituted by "1000".

```js
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(), '17,30')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText =  '1000'", element)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this instead:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(), '17,30')]")
newprice= str(element.text).replace('17,30',"1000")
driver.execute_script(f"var e = arguments[0]; e.innerText = '{newprice}'", element)
```